# Serializing a Kotlin delegate with Gson

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have a Kotlin object that I am trying serialize with Gson.  A member that is setup as a delegate does not get serialized.  The delegation works if I call it directly, as does the onChange callback, but Gson just ignores it.

Is there any way to get Gson to serialize this without writing a custom serializer?

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class MyDelegate() {

    fun getProperty(): String {
        return "myDelegate Property"
    }

    fun observableDelegate(onChange: () -> Unit): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, String> {

        return object: ReadWriteProperty<Any?, String> {
            override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
                return getProperty()
            }

            override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
                TODO("not implemented")
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyTest(delegate: MyDelegate, val property0: String = "property0" ) {

    val property1 = "property1"
    var property2 = "property2"
    var property3: String by delegate.observableDelegate {
        // onChange called
    }
}
```

Testing it with:

```
@Test
    fun testDelegate() {

        val t1 = MyTest(MyDelegate())
        val s1 = Gson().toJson(t1)

        Assert.fail(s1)

    }
```

Output:

```
{"property1":"property1","property2":"property2","property0":"property0"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property3` variable is not field backed. Thus *Gson* doesn't consider it as field in the *Json* serialization.

The [GsonDesignDocument](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/GsonDesignDocument.md) states for properties as such

> Some Json libraries use the getters of a type to deduce the Json elements. We chose to use all fields (up the inheritance hierarchy) that are not transient, static, or synthetic. We did this because not all classes are written with suitably named getters. Moreover, getXXX or isXXX might be semantic rather than indicating properties.

So you might have to implement a custom (de)serializer for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, came to that conclusion also after staring at the getValue() call in the delegate for about a minute...